# BackgroundWorker process needs to raise custom events to be handled on the main (UI) thread

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, synchronizationcontext

I have a parser class for large CSV files.  The parse method's work of reading through the large files line by line is done in a backgroundWorker. The percentage complete information is passed to the UI thread using the `backgroundWorker.ReportProgress` method, so that a progress bar on my form can do its thing.  That's working fine.

However, I would also like to raise a custom event that sends back to the UI (WPF) a list of fieldnames taken from the first line of the CSV file, so that they can be placed in a dropdown list. I would also like to inform the user via an event if the parser should encounter malformed lines or other roadblocks.

Can my parser process executing in the background simply raise an event? Or must the SynchronizationContext.Current be passed from the main UI thread to my parser class, which would then use the Post method?

Comment: Make a class that inherits from `BackgroundWorker`, make your own event, call it from your worker's `DoWork` method?

Comment: @gunr2171 - this does not solve the problem as the event will still be raised on the background thread (and therefore its handlers will run on the background thread too) if you do it inside the DoWork handler. Some means of scheduling work on the UI thread will still be required.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy, yes, you raise the event from the `DoWork` method, but you subscribe to it from outside the worker. You would have to do a bit of invoking (I think) to get it back into the main thread, but this should not hang up the worker thread.

Comment: Consider using `Task` and async/await instead.

Comment: Also consider creating an IObserver on your UI thead using Reactive Extensions.

Comment: @gunr2171 "call it from your worker's DoWork method"... doesn't detail the invoke part...

Comment: @PeterRitchie calling the event from the worker does not require an invoke. Subscribing to the event and pulling into the main UI thread does.

Comment: @gunr2171 right, you didn't detail the invoke part... It's clear the OP doesn't get that part...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you *absolutely must* schedule work on the UI thread from within your `DoWork` handler, the simplest way to do this is by using `Dispatcher.Invoke`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
        {
            // Suppose we've done some processing and need to notify the UI.
            // We're on the background thread, so we can't manipulate the UI directly.
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                // This will actually run on the UI thread.
                this.Label.Content = "hello from the background thread.";
            }));
        };

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

There seems to be a lot of confusion about events and their magical ability to do thread synchronization, so allow me to rant for a bit.

Events are glorified multicast delegates. When you raise an event, each delegate in its invocation list is called, *on the thread which raised the event*. Therefore, if you create an event in your custom parser class just to have it raised from the `DoWork` handler, the handlers for the event will still execute on the background thread, and you will still need to find a way to switch to the UI synchronization context - either by performing some `Invoke`/`SynchronizationContext.Post`/`Send` magic inside the handler of the new event, OR by Invoking/Posting/Sending the actual event raise logic.

The reason that handlers for out-of-the-box events such as `RunWorkerCompleted` and `ProgressChanged` run on the UI thread is that these events are *actually raised* on the UI thread by the `BackgroundWorker` for your convenience. And yes, you can produce similar behaviour by capturing the `SynchronizationContext` and then Posting/Sending the event raise logic in your custom parser class to it. Alternatively, if you choose to raise the event on the background thread, you can always use `Dispatcher.Invoke` inside its handler in your WPF component.